# How to write a text file in another with editing in C

Tags: c, file

So I'm pretty new to files, and I'm making a function that is supposed to copy the text from a file to another and writing a number instead of ?. This was my initial approach:

```
void generate(int n, const int numbers[]){

    FILE *tpl = fopen("code.tpl", "r");
    FILE *file = fopen("code.c", "w");
    char text[N];
    int i, j;

    fgets(text, N, tpl);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(text[i] == '?'){
            text[i]= ' ';
            fprintf(file, "%d", n);
        }
        fprintf(file, "%c", text[i]);
    }


      fclose(file);
      fclose(tpl);

}
```

The code doesn't work and it writes an unreadable character in code.c

Comment: Please describe what specific problem you have with the code? Does it crash? Does it produce the wrong values sometimes? Wrong values all the time? What?

Comment: In your question there are no... questions. Anyway, if I understand correctly what you are trying to do, in case of ``'?' you write to the target file both the number and the question mark. An `else` is required after that `if`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni He's not writing the `?` because he does `text[i] = ' '`, so he writes a space after the number rather than the question mark.

Comment: @TomKarzes He replaces `?` with space in `text[i]`.

Comment: @Barmar you are right.

Comment: Side note: You sould always check if the opening of a stream was successful by checking the returned pointer for a null pointer.

Comment: N is defined as 100 and I added a loop ```while(fgets(text, N, tpl))``` it prints a lot of unreadable characters in the file. for the '?' The way I wanted to remove it is change it to a space.

Comment: @Barmar Oh right - so it's printing a space instead of `'?'`.  It still doesn't match the claimed intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unreadable characters are probably because the line is shorter than `N` characters, so you're copying uninitialized characters to the output file. The loop should stop when it reaches the null terminator in `text`.

There's also no need to use `fprintf()` just to write a single character, use the simpler `fputc()`. And instead of replacing `text[i]` with a space, you can include that in the format string when writing `n`.

```
    for(i = 0; text[i] != 0; i++){
        if(text[i] == '?'){
            fprintf(file, "%d ", n);
        } else {
            fputc(text[i], file);
        }
    }
```

If the file has multiple lines, you need to read the lines in a loop, not just a single line:

```
while (fgets(text, N, tpl)) {
    for(i = 0; text[i] != 0; i++){
        if(text[i] == '?'){
            fprintf(file, "%d ", n);
        } else {
            fputc(text[i], file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain that he really wants more than one line (maybe it's a one-line file). But his question is about the garbage characters, this explains how to fix that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it in a loop.